# Why does my function only returns the first object from the array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm writing note module for a student organizer web app. I wrote a function to fetch an object by its ID but it's not working properly or I have a problem in another part of my code but I can't figure it out.

This function should return the names of categories and subjects. Somehow it returns only the first name from category & subject Array.

**My Attempt:**

```
findMyObjectByID = function (objArray, id) {
for (const obj of objArray){
  if (+obj._ID === +id) {
    console.log('--------------------');
    console.log(obj._ID + ' | ' + id );
    console.log(obj._Name);
    console.log('--------------------');
    return obj._Name;
  } else {
    console.log('--------------------');
    console.log(obj._ID + ' | ' + id );
    console.log('ELSE');
    console.log('--------------------');
    return 'undefined';
  }
}
};
```

I tested the function in a blank project without View. No Problem here. https://pastebin.com/n2JZhMGW

**HTML/Angular - form & view**
I choose a category and a subject. There are different options for the note categories. 1&2 are with deadline and subject input fields and 3 is just title and text. So this is my HTML/Angular form and view.

```
<input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)] = "Title" placeholder="Titel">
<select name="Category" [(ngModel)] = "Category">
  <option *ngFor="let category of Categorys" value="{{category._ID}}">{{category._Name}}</option>
</select>

<div [ngSwitch]="Category">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1">
    <select name="subject" [(ngModel)] = "Subject">
      <option *ngFor="let subject of Subjects" value="{{subject._ID}}">{{subject._Name}}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="deadline" [(ngModel)] = "Enddate" placeholder="Deadline eintragen">
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="2">
    <select name="subject" [(ngModel)] = "Subject">
      <option *ngFor="let subject of Subjects" value="{{subject._ID}}">
{{subject._Name}}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="deadline" [(ngModel)] = "Enddate" placeholder="Deadline eintragen">
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div *ngIf="Category == 1 || Category == 2 || Category == 3">
  <input type="text" name="note" [(ngModel)] = "Note" placeholder="Notiz">
</div>
<hr>
  <button (click) = "add()">Save me</button>
<hr>
<div class="noteBox">
  <h1>Notizen </h1>
  <div class="note"  *ngFor="let note of Notes">
    <h2>{{note._Title}}</h2>
    <span>{{note._DateCreated}} | {{note._CategoryName}}</span>
    <span>Fach: {{note._SubjectName}} | Ablaufdatum: {{note._Enddate}}</span>
    <hr>
    <article>
      {{note._Content}}
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Typescript - data & object creation**
The values of the selectboxes are the ids of the subject and category objects which will later represent the database ids. This is how I create my instance of the note object.

```
add = function () {
// id, title, content, subjectID, subjectName, userID, userName, categoryID, categoryName, dateCreated, enddate
this.Notes.push(new Note(0, this.Title, this.Note, this.Subject, this.findMyObjectByID(this.Subjects, this.Subject), 0, 'admin', this.Category, this.findMyObjectByID(this.Categorys, this.Category), '2017-05-18', this.Enddate));
this.Note = '';
this.Title = '';
this.Category = 0;
this.Enddate = '';
this.Subject = 0;
};
```

If it's helpful: this is my data. Since I have no data source yet the data is hard coded.

```
   constructor() {
    this.addSubjects();
    this.addCategorys();
  }

  addSubjects = function () {
    this.Subjects.push(new Subject(89, 'math'));
    this.Subjects.push(new Subject(16, 'german'));
    this.Subjects.push(new Subject(45, 'english'));
    this.Subjects.push(new Subject(89, 'ped'));
  };

  addCategorys = function () {
    this.Categorys.push(new Category(45, 'homework'));
    this.Categorys.push(new Category(13, 'reminder'));
    this.Categorys.push(new Category(27, 'fastnote'));
  };
```

Complete app.component.ts file: https://pastebin.com/LrUWYgpX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop will exit if the first `id` is not equal to the first element in the `objArray` because you have a `return 'undefined'` inside the loop.

I think the correct way to do it is to move the return statement out of the loop

```
  findMyObjectByID = function (objArray, id) {
    for (const obj of objArray) {
      if (+obj._ID === +id) {
        console.log(obj._Name);
        return obj._Name;
      }
    }
    return 'undefined';
  }
```

Comment: Thank yout for the answer but that didn't work. I modified the function and found out that the propertys of the 'obj' object value doest not change if i add the second note. https://pastebin.com/cQnd1WfF

Comment: In your pastebin you still have the `return 'undefined';` inside the loop, so if the first element is not the correct ID you will **always** return 'undefined'. You need have it outside the loop. 

Your loop should look for every element in the array and return 'undefined' only when it has looked through **all** elements and not found the one you look for.

see here https://pastebin.com/aTgKubNn

Comment: Okay my mistake. Works fine now. Thanks :)